# Osculating duality for curves (reference request)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Suppose that $C\subset\mathbb P^n$ is a projective curve (over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$) not lying in a hyperplane; denote by $C^*\subset(\mathbb P^n)^*$ the closure of the set of hyperplanes osculating to $C$ at smooth points. It is well known that $(C^*)^*=C$ and, moreover, $k$-dimensional osculating space to $C^*$ (at the generic point) coincides with the annihilator of the corresponding $n-k-1$-dimensional osculating space to $C$.

> When and by whom was this first proved? Could you give a reference?

(edit: a typo corrected)
Thank you in advance,
Serge

Comment: This is due to Cayley and Veronese. A reference is a book by Bertini, Geometria proiettiva degli iperspazi, available here: https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=R4sLAAAAYAAJ&rdid=book-R4sLAAAAYAAJ&rdot=1

Comment: @Felipe: Thanks, I will try to obtain the book.

Comment: The reference I knew was for the 1923 edition of Bertini's book but I just noticed that the edition on google books is the 1907 edition. So it may not be there.

Comment: Is there nothing more recent?

Comment: I thought you wanted a historical reference. Otherwise, Piene, R., Numerical characters of a curve in projective n-space, Real and Complex Singularities, Sijthoff and Noordhoff, Alphen aan den Rijn, 1977, Thm. 5.1

Comment: Another thing you might want to keep in mind is that the case $n=2$, which is the first interesting case was worked out carefully by Julius Plücker and published in 1830 (so it long predates the works by Cayley and Veronese).  It was Plücker's work explaining why the dual of the dual has the same degree as the original in terms of 'defects' and 'singularities' that led to the Plücker relations, which are the precursor to all of the relations in the higher dimensions.  It would be interesting to know to what extent Plücker's work influenced or motivated Cayley and Veronese in higher dimensions.